# How to write coefficients sum of polynomial product $\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}c_{k}x^{k}$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

If we have two polynomials written in form $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i} \text{ and }  \sum_{j=0}^{m}b_{j}x^{j}$ and their product is $\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}c_{k}x^{k}$, how can we write sum of their coefficients when we know:

$c_{0}=a_{0}b_{0}$

$c_{1}=a_{0}b_{1}+a_{1}b_{0}$

$c_{2}=a_{0}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{0}$

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one compact way of writing it.

$c_i=\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_jb_{i-j}$

Just look at the pattern that you have created. The coefficient of $x^{i}$ is created from multiplying the powers of $x$, that their exponent add up to $i$. So, if you have $ax^d$ in the first polymomial and $bx^{i-d}$, in the second polynomial, they would make a term $ab x^i$, that contributes to the coefficient of $x^{i}$.

Comment: I found that also but i don't know how to prove that? How can i derive that compact form from $c_{0}+c_{1}...+c_{n+m}$?

Comment: @ZvnokyBrown, I have added a few more lines. Hope it helps. But I think you should not try to derive from the sum that you have mentioned.